How to manage non ASCII characters inside sh/bash scripts
My terminal.txt file in the sequel
shows the output of my tmpPdfFile.sh and tmpPdfFile1.sh scripts:
both scripts are unable to properly manage the file
"6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf"
The problem is with the accented character! No error is raised when processing the file
"6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf"
Note that if I zip all files, the problem remains, while if I tar them, no error is raised!
How can I modify my scripts in order to deal with non-ASCII chars properly?
Here is my tmpPdfFile.sh:
    #!/bin/bash -x
    echo "usage: $0 <pdf file (with extension)>"
    scriptName=`basename $0 .sh`
    filePath="$1"
    fileName=`basename $filePath .pdf`
    fileDir=`dirname $filePath`
    pdftk "${fileDir}/${fileName}.pdf" cat output "${fileDir}/${fileName}-stamp.pdf"

See terminal.txt below:
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ diff tmpPdfFile.sh tmpPdfFile1.sh 
    1c1
    < #!/bin/bash -x
    ---
    > #!/bin/sh -x
    7c7
    < pdftk "${fileDir}/${fileName}.pdf" cat output "${fileDir}/${fileName}-stamp.pdf"
    ---
    > pdftk "${fileDir}/${fileName}.pdf" cat output "${fileDir}/${fileName}-stamp1.pdf"
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ ./tmpPdfFile1.sh 6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    + echo usage: ./tmpPdfFile1.sh <pdf file (with extension)>
    usage: ./tmpPdfFile1.sh <pdf file (with extension)>
    + basename ./tmpPdfFile1.sh .sh
    + scriptName=tmpPdfFile1
    + filePath=6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    + basename 6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf .pdf
    + fileName=6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx
    + dirname 6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    + fileDir=.
    + pdftk ./6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf cat output ./6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx-stamp1.pdf
    Error: Unable to find file.
    Error: Failed to open input PDF file: 
       ./6._ANberta??_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    Errors encountered.  No output created.
    Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ ./tmpPdfFile1.sh 6._ANber
    6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf  6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf  
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ ./tmpPdfFile1.sh 6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf 
    + echo usage: ./tmpPdfFile1.sh <pdf file (with extension)>
    usage: ./tmpPdfFile1.sh <pdf file (with extension)>
    + basename ./tmpPdfFile1.sh .sh
    + scriptName=tmpPdfFile1
    + filePath=6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ ./tmpPdfFile.sh 6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf 
    + echo 'usage: ./tmpPdfFile.sh <pdf file (with extension)>'
    usage: ./tmpPdfFile.sh <pdf file (with extension)>
    ++ basename ./tmpPdfFile.sh .sh
    + scriptName=tmpPdfFile
    + filePath=6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    ++ basename 6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf .pdf
    + fileName=6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx
    ++ dirname 6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    + fileDir=.
    + pdftk ./6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf cat output ./6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx-stamp.pdf
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ ./tmpPdfFile.sh 6._ANberta                      
    6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx-stamp.pdf  6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf        6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ ./tmpPdfFile.sh 6._ANberta
    6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx-stamp.pdf  6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf        6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ ./tmpPdfFile.sh 6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    + echo 'usage: ./tmpPdfFile.sh <pdf file (with extension)>'
    usage: ./tmpPdfFile.sh <pdf file (with extension)>
    ++ basename ./tmpPdfFile.sh .sh
    + scriptName=tmpPdfFile
    + filePath=$'6._ANberta\314\200_di_scelta.docx.pdf'
    ++ basename $'6._ANberta\314\200_di_scelta.docx.pdf' .pdf
    + fileName=$'6._ANberta\314\200_di_scelta.docx'
    ++ dirname $'6._ANberta\314\200_di_scelta.docx.pdf'
    + fileDir=.
    + pdftk $'./6._ANberta\314\200_di_scelta.docx.pdf' cat output $'./6._ANberta\314\200_di_scelta.docx-stamp.pdf'
    Error: Unable to find file.
    Error: Failed to open input PDF file: 
       ./6._ANberta??_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    Errors encountered.  No output created.
    Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ ./tmpPdfFils1.sh 6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    bash: ./tmpPdfFile.s1h: No such file or directory
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash                
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ lst
    total 44K
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 sartoret sartoret 11K Jun 27 14:27 '6._ANberta'$'\314\200''_di_scelta.docx.pdf'
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 sartoret sartoret 11K Jun 27 14:27  6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 sartoret sartoret  1K Jun 27 14:32  tmpPdfFile1.sh
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 sartoret sartoret  1K Jun 27 14:32  tmpPdfFile.sh
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 sartoret sartoret 11K Jun 27 14:34  6._ANbertata_di_scelta.docx-stamp.pdf
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ ./tmpPdfFile1.sh '6._ANberta'$'\314\200''_di_scelta.docx.pdf'
    + echo usage: ./tmpPdfFile1.sh <pdf file (with extension)>
    usage: ./tmpPdfFile1.sh <pdf file (with extension)>
    + basename ./tmpPdfFile1.sh .sh
    + scriptName=tmpPdfFile1
    + filePath=6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    + basename 6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf .pdf
    + fileName=6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx
    + dirname 6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    + fileDir=.
    + pdftk ./6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx.pdf cat output ./6._ANbertà_di_scelta.docx-stamp1.pdf
    Error: Unable to find file.
    Error: Failed to open input PDF file: 
       ./6._ANberta??_di_scelta.docx.pdf
    Errors encountered.  No output created.
    Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
    sartoret@linux-laptop:~/tools/bash$ 

I tried both "bash" and "sh" shells, I dumped the files by "zip" and "tar", hence obtaining different behaviors.

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your code, input, and output as Code Blocks then [edit] your question accordingly.

@KJ: Would this mean, that zip also does not allow (for instance) a colon or backslash in the file name (forbidden in Windows)? Also, AFIK, on MacOS some characters may be disallowed dependend on the file system.

How about first creating a tar (giving the tar some "safe" name) and then zipping the tar, to reduce space?

@KJ : Interesting remark. I would not have expected problems with a ' character in filenames, since this is pretty much conventional, and AFIK even the earliest Unix platforms would not bail out on them. The upper/lower case names can cause trouble on case-insensitive file systems, and I darkly remember having read that someone reported problems on MacOS with filenames containing some unicode emoticon characters.

For my job I work with a lot of user created files, and I've seen crimes against humanity. Tabs, colons, slashes of every kind, asterisks, enters.. all in filenames.
Be very sure you quote everything in your bash script, so never a $x but always "$x". Never `basename $x` but always "`basename $x`". But even then you're likely to run into trouble.
Sometimes it might be best to sanitize filenames before you work with them. You can either go the brute force way and nuke anything non-ASCII:
NEW_FILENAME="$(echo $OLD_FILENAME | LC_ALL=C sed 's/[\d128-\d255]//g')"
mv "$OLD_FILENAME" "$NEW_FILENAME"
# Or create a temp copy with a new name

Or you can use iconv for more flexability:
export LC_ALL=C          # Just to be sure

echo "Sjögren" | hexdump -C
00000000  53 6a c3 b6 67 72 65 6e  0a                       |Sj..gren.|

# Simply trying to convert it to ASCII gives an error since
# it cannot map o-umlaut to anything in the ASCII table
echo "Sjögren" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 2

# The -c flag removes invalid sequences
# (or anything it cannot translate to the other character set)
echo "Sjögren" | iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t ASCII
Sjgren

# You can tell iconv to convert as best as it can, for example
# the o with umlaut to a regular o
echo "Sjögren" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
Sjogren

# Translates what it can and removes what it can't,
# guaranteeing ASCII output
echo "Sjögren" | iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
Sjogren


Thank you Ren for your valuable suggestions. I am trying to sanitize my entire directory tree, which is full with non-ASCII, apostrophes, blanks and parentheses. I replace blank with underscore, parentheses with dash, non-ASCII with ASCII "equivalent". I do it by python, which seems more friendly  than bash...

"\basename $x`"isn't good enough. It should be"$( basename "$x" )". Even then, you'll have problems with file names that start with a -. So "$( basename -- "$x" )"` is even better.
